# imacros relative positioning in cell

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to use imacros on this site: http://www.philsp.com/homeville/FMI/t/t363.htm#A7331 to find the covers and publication info for short stories I have in my collection. I have my code working OK except for extracting the publication info at the top of the cells.

In this example my code has searched and found:  "Simple Gifts" by "Maya Kaathryn Bohnhoff", and saved the cover. I now want it to go to the top of the cell and save the publication info, which in this example is: "Analog Science Fiction and Fact [v130 # 1 & 2, January/February 2010]"

Whatever I try jumps to the top of the top cell on the page. Can anyone help me out with this. 
Thanks.

```
VERSION BUILD=8031994
TAB T=1  
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

URL GOTO=http://www.philsp.com/homeville/FMI/t/t363.htm#A7331
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI ATTR=TXT:*Simple<SP>Gifts*

ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\Covers  FILE=cover.jpg WAIT=YES
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*http://www.philsp.com/data/images*.jpg CONTENT=EVENT:SAVETARGETAS
```

EDIT:

This seems to work as the popup shows the correct text to extract but the saveas still saves the text from the very top of the page. I dont understand why, any ideas?

```
URL GOTO=http://www.philsp.com/homeville/FMI/t/t363.htm 
SET title *Simple<SP>Gifts* 

TAG POS=1 TYPE=UL ATTR=TXT:{{title}} EXTRACT=TXT SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"<a.+><i>(.+)\].+" EXTRACT="$1"

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP YES
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\imacros FILE=results.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, the following code would be helpful:

```
SET title *Simple<SP>Gifts*
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=UL ATTR=TXT:{{title}} EXTRACT=TXT
SET info EVAL("var s = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\".match(/\\n(.*)\\n/)[1]; s;")
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. (See my edit above) I'm no good with Eval statements so I use Regex. Your code seems to work as the popup has the correct text but it still saves the wrong text from the top of the page. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because you use the command: `SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"<a.+><i>(.+)\].+" EXTRACT="$1"` that overrides my `!EXTRACT` (shown in a popup window). If you wish to see the right text, just add the command `PROMPT {{info}}` at the end of my code. It does work!